# How to represent that One entity is not a part of other entity in Conceptual ERD

Tags: database-design, erd

In a conceptual ERD using crowsfoot notation, How can we represent that one entity is not considered as another entity? I think that if we don't connect these two entities in the ERD, then it is taken care of. Please correct me if I am wrong.